# Interfacing Arduino with a Web app Ruby on Rails through wireless

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, arduino, interfacing

I want to start a small project with my arduino. The idea is to have this communication flow:

arduino <-> wireless board <-> Wi-Fi router <-> Web Server <-> Ruby on Rails 3 <-> Smart Phone <-> Browser

I found a framework called RAD (Ruby Arduino Development) but the last update is from 2008. Does anyone know another option to this?

Comment: What wireless board are you using?  Each shield generally has its own interface and library.

Comment: I don't have it yet, I want to make sure that it is feasible and then buy the components.

Answer (score 1):

The [WiShield](http://www.asynclabs.com/store?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=26&category_id=6) has libraries that can talk basic TCP/IP.  The [source code](https://github.com/asynclabs/WiShield) has [an example HTTP client](https://raw.github.com/asynclabs/WiShield/master/examples/WebClient/webclient.c).  This can be used as a basis for a client that makes requests to a rails server.

The WiShield seems to be available in a bunch of places.

Answer (score 0):

You could send sensor values through the internet via an Ethernet shield like the **ENC28J60** with the **EtherCard** library. Then you could make an RESTful API on your Rails app (e.g. with Grape), and from the Arduino shield, send the info to this API using the **EtherCard** library that I suggest.

If you want to use wifi capabilities, the concept it's the same, but instead of use an Ethernet shield, use a wifi shield [like this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoWiFiShield).

[Here you have](http://dreamingechoes.github.io/arduino/ruby/rails/physical-software-made-easy-with-arduino-and-ruby-on-rails/) an example to do it with an Ethernet shield.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10717161)

Comment: Totally Agree with that. I sent this response at work, and as I didn't have time to answer properly, I answered with the link directly, but when I have more time I'll complete it to make it as useful as possible. Thank you very much! :)